# PHP convert flat to nested multidimensional array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some data that is coming from a mysql query in a flat array this way:

```
  0 => Array 
    indcode => "A00"
    indlabel => "Code label text"
    description => "More explanations"
  1 => Array 
    indcode => "NA0"
    indlabel => "Un-classified A"
    description => "Un-classified A"
  2 => Array (3)
    indcode => "A01"
    indlabel => "Code Label text"
    description => "More explanations"
  3 => Array (3)
    indcode => "A02"
    indlabel => "Code label text"
    description => "More explanations"
```

I would like to nest it that way:

```
  A00 => Array 
    indlabel => "Code label text"
    description => "More explanations"
  NA0 => Array 
    indlabel => "Un-classified A"
    description => "Un-classified A"
  A01 => Array 
    indlabel => "Code Label text"
    description => "More explanations"
  A02 => Array
    indlabel => "Code label text"
    description => "More explanations"
```

So in my CMS I found in use a very neat code which does the nesting :

```
foreach ($dimsDesc as $desc) {
$descriptions[$desc['indcode']][$desc['indlabel']] = $desc['description'];
}
```

That works but I didn't find how to keep the indlabel and description at the same level (= the other side of the equal sign).

Also, if you have links to some other examples or a good reference for this construct, it would be appreciated because I will use this a lot to build dynamic reports... And for now PDO queries are a bit out of my reach. I also used `array_column()` with `NULL` which works but I have more complex data structures incoming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just change your `foreach` loop in the following way,

```
foreach ($dimsDesc as $desc) {
    $descriptions[$desc['indcode']]['indlabel'] = $desc['indlabel'];
    $descriptions[$desc['indcode']]['description'] = $desc['description'];
}
```

**Or,**

```
foreach ($dimsDesc as $desc) {
    $descriptions[$desc['indcode']] = array('indlabel' => $desc['indlabel'], 'description' => $desc['description']);
}
```

Here's the documentation,

- [Creating/modifying arrays with square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

Comment: Thanks, all do work, but especially the first example that even if it looks somehow less neat than the second, it helped me to understand what I had missed !

Comment: Thanks indeed. I was wondering if there is some (book, online documentation, ...) where I can find some examples or explanations. I was especially wondering why this works (instead of overwriting the values or duplicating the arrays...)..

Comment: @Joel.O Here's the documentation, [http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
foreach ($dimsDesc as $desc) {
    $descriptions[$desc['indcode']] = array( 
        'indlabel' => $desc['indlabel'], 
        'description' => $desc['description']
    );
}
?>
```